# Problema al captar SocketException

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy intentando implementar un chat grupal en Java. El chat esta completamente funcional, (lo básico). Mi intención es captar **cuando un usuario se desconecta** para poder borrar su nombre del arrayList de usuarios del servidor, pero no consigo identificar cuando se desconecta. He colocado un try/catch en mi servidor para captar el **SocketException**, pero nunca entra allí.

Mi código de mi servidor es el siguiente:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServerChat {

    static ArrayList<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();

    static ArrayList<PrintWriter> printWriters = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();

    public ServerChat() {
        usuarios = null;
        printWriters = null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {

        try {

            System.out.println("Esperando por peticiones de clientes... ");
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9001);


            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket soc = ss.accept(); // representa al cliente
                    System.out.println("Cliente conectado. ");

                    ManejadorConver manejador = new ManejadorConver(soc, usuarios.size());
                    manejador.start();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    System.out.println("Se ha desconectado un cliente");
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Código Cliente:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ClienteChat {

    static JFrame ventanaChat = new JFrame("Aplicación Chat CS");
    static JTextArea areaChat = new JTextArea(22, 40); // (filas, columnas)
    static JTextField campoTexto = new JTextField(40);
    static JLabel espacioBlanco = new JLabel("      ");
    static JButton botonEnvio = new JButton("Enviar");
    static JLabel nombreSesion = new JLabel("       ");

    static BufferedReader entrada;
    static PrintWriter salida;

    public ClienteChat() {

        ventanaChat.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ventanaChat.add(nombreSesion);
        ventanaChat.add(new JScrollPane(areaChat));
        ventanaChat.add(espacioBlanco);
        ventanaChat.add(campoTexto);
        ventanaChat.add(botonEnvio);

        ventanaChat.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        ventanaChat.setSize(475, 500); 
        ventanaChat.setVisible(true); 

        campoTexto.setEditable(false); 
        areaChat.setEditable(false);
        botonEnvio.addActionListener(new Listener());
        campoTexto.addActionListener(new Listener());

    }

    public void encenderCliente() throws Exception {

        String dirIP = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ventanaChat, "Introduce dirección IP:", "Direcciï¿½n IP requerida",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        Socket socket = new Socket(dirIP, 9001);
        entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        salida = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while (true) {

            String str = entrada.readLine();
            String nombre = null;

             if (str.equals("NOMBRENECESARIO")) {

                nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ventanaChat, "Introduce un nickname único:",
                        "Nickname requerido", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                salida.println(nombre);

            } else if (str.equals("NOMBREPREEXISTENTE")) {

                nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ventanaChat, "Introduce otro nickname:", "Este nickname ya existe",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                salida.println(nombre);

            } else if (str.startsWith("NOMBREACEPTADO")) {

                campoTexto.setEditable(true); 
                nombreSesion.setText("Has hecho login con el nombre: " + str.substring(14));

            } else {

                areaChat.append(str + "\n");

            }    

        }

    }

    class Listener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String texto = ClienteChat.campoTexto.getText();

            ClienteChat.salida.println(texto);
            ClienteChat.campoTexto.setText("");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClienteChat cliente = new ClienteChat();
        cliente.encenderCliente();
    }

}
```

Código Manejador:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ManejadorConver extends Thread {

    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader entrada;
    PrintWriter salida;
    String nombre;

    public ManejadorConver(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            int i = 0;
            entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            salida = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while (true) {


                if (i > 0) {
                    salida.println("NOMBREPREEXISTENTE");
                } else {
                    salida.println("NOMBRENECESARIO");
                }

                nombre = entrada.readLine();

                if (nombre == null) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!ServerChat.usuarios.contains(nombre)) {

                    ServerChat.usuarios.add(nombre);
                    break;
                }

                i++;

            }

            salida.println("NOMBREACEPTADO" + nombre);
            ServerChat.printWriters.add(salida);

            while (true) {
                String mensaje = entrada.readLine();

                if (mensaje == null) {
                    return;
                }

                for (PrintWriter writer : ServerChat.printWriters) {

                    writer.println(nombre + ": " + mensaje);

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);

        }

    }
}
```

**PROBLEMA**: nunca entra en ese try - catch y no consigo captar la desconexión.

La consola me muestra esto cuando cierro la ventana de un cliente:

> Esperando por peticiones de clientes... Cliente conectado. java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

...pero no entra en ese `try catch` que he puesto en el servidor para captar justo esa `Exception`.

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que sí sucede? Se escapa alguna excepción...?  Se queda esperando en el `ss.accept()`..? Otra cosa ..?

Comment: La consola me muestra esto cuando cierro la ventana de un cliente: `Esperando por peticiones de clientes... 
Cliente conectado. 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset `. Pero no entra en ese try catch que he puesto en el servidor para captar justo esa Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la excepción `SocketException` es lanzada desde un hilo distinto al del `main`.

Cuando aceptas una conexión de cliente en el `main`, la instancia del socket se lo pasas a la instancia de la clase `ManejadorConver`, que corre en un hilo distinto:

```
ManejadorConver manejador = new ManejadorConver(soc, usuarios.size());
manejador.start(); // <-- esto corre en otro hilo
```

Cualquier excepción que surja mientra se ejecuta `manejador.start()` no la podrás atrapar en el `main()`.

Mas bien, **el lugar donde debes manejar el `SocketException` es en el método `ManejadorConver.run()`**. Y de hecho, allí ya tienes un `try-catch` que hace lo siguiente y que explica el mensaje que recibes en la consola:

```
   } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);

    }
```

Es en ese lugar que debes agregar un exception handler para manejar la desconexión del cliente.

Ejemplo:

```
} catch (SocketException e) {
    System.out.println("Se ha desconectado un cliente");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

... aunque toma en cuenta que un `SocketException` puede ocurrir por varias razones, y no todas implican que el cliente se desconectó. Algo a tomar en cuenta.

Comment: Vaya, tienes razón. Pero cómo podría comunicárselo al servidor? :( Perdón por mi bajo nivel, aun no me manejo muy bien.

Comment: Creo que la parte final de la respuesta contesta esta ultima duda. ¿Quedó claro?